# Css layout using inline-block instead of floats

Tags: layout, css-float, css

How can I create this layout, using `inline-block`, instead of `float`s?
The only change that can be made to the HTML, is the order of #A and #B.

http://jsfiddle.net/a2envebj/4/

The HTML:

```
<div id="root">
  <div id="A"></div>
  <div id="B"></div>
  <div id="C"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#root {
    width:450px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#A {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height:240px;
    background-color: green;
}
#B {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height:120px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#C {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried and why do you need to make the change?

Comment: If you are asking, can you build this layout using this HTML without using any floats, and using only inline-blocks, I would say no.  However, this answer may not help you.  Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do, thanks!

Comment: It's possible to build the layout but only by amending the markup to wrap B & C - http://jsfiddle.net/a2envebj/13/

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D - i've tried.. and no, i can't wrap it, in the original code i have more elements and they must all be on the same level for semantic reasons, as well as for jQuery calls.

Comment: Thanks @MarcAudet, please read my answer to @ Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

markup:

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="C"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#root {
    width:450px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#A {
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    background-color: #008000;
    display: inline-block;
}
#B {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #FF0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
#C {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
}
```

no extra markup needed - tricky one, I like that :)

Comment: Thanks, but the `position:absolute` is rendering the `inline-block` useless.. and it is what i need.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that earlier. Any other constraints? You might need to resort to extra wrapper or some js solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this suits your needs or not, but you would have to wrap the 2 smaller DIV and then display this new DIV inline with the larger green DIV

http://jsfiddle.net/a2envebj/11/

As we are using inline-block, we have to remove the white space between the DIVs

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="A"></div><div id="wrap">
        <div id="B"></div>
        <div id="C"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## wrap {

```
width:200px;
height:240px;
background:#000;
display:inline-block;
```

}

## A {

```
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height:240px;
background-color: green;
```

}

## B {

```
display: block;
width: 200px;
height:120px;
background-color: yellow;
```

}

## C {

```
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
background-color: orange;
```

}